# Why am I receiving java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashset, bluej

Whenever I call the pennyCount method or the removePenny method I get a null pointer exception error which I dont understand as my HashSet should be populated in the constructor. Why am I getting this and how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Pocket
{

private HashSet<Penny> penniesSet;



public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

    HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

    for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
        penniesSet.add(new Penny());}



}

public int pennyCount(){
    return penniesSet.size();

}

public Penny removePenny(){

    if(penniesSet.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        Penny toRemove = penniesSet.iterator().next();
        penniesSet.remove(toRemove);
        return toRemove;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: something be null. so you get NullPointerException.:)

Answer (score 1):

You create two HashSet with the same name one field and one local in the constructor. What will happen is that the local variable will be instantiated. The field will still be null by the time you reach pennyCount().

```
private HashSet<Penny> penniesSet; //first here

public Pocket(int numOfPennies){
    HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>(); //then here
```

To correct do like this.

```
private HashSet<Penny> penniesSet;

public Pocket(int numOfPennies){
    penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you have following

```
HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();
```

It should be

```
penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you are declaring a new HashSet penniesSet , it should be:

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

        penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

        for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
            penniesSet.add(new Penny());}
}
```

Otherwise you're pennieSet is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

    penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>(); // was HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

    for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
        penniesSet.add(new Penny());}



}
```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but could you add an explanation for how this fixes the OPs problem?

Comment: my answer is the as everyone elses, what oop problem?

Comment: Most of them go into a little detail about why changing that line fixes it (ie that the variable is shadowed when OP re-declares it). I commented on your answer because I saw it in the review queue (since it's mostly code). Just an FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

change like this.

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

    penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

    for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
        penniesSet.add(new Penny());}

}
```

Comment: It would be good if you explained, what the problem with the OP was and how you solve it here.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

    HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

    for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
        penniesSet.add(new Penny());}



}
```

to

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){

    penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>(); //set the instance variable instead of creating a local variable

    for(int n = 0; n < numOfPennies; n++){
        penniesSet.add(new Penny());}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Set object in constructor instead of populating the field of your class. Try:

```
penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();
```